# android.media3.ui.PlayerView randomly crashes with AudioTrack -12

Tags: android, exoplayer

I have simple activity with PlayerView inside where on start I am playing video by given url.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    android:background="@color/black"">

    <androidx.media3.ui.PlayerView
        android:id="@+id/playerview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Activity class:

```
 private var player: ExoPlayer? = null
 private val dataSourceFactory: DataSource.Factory = DefaultHttpDataSource.Factory()

 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityWallMediaBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)
    this.setFinishOnTouchOutside(true);

    displayVideo(/*url from intent*/)       
  }

 override fun onStop() {
    super.onStop()
    releasePlayer()
 }

  @Suppress("NAME_SHADOWING")
  @OptIn(UnstableApi::class)
  private fun displayVideo(source: String) {
      binding.imageView.visibility = View.GONE;
      player = ExoPlayer.Builder(this)
         .build()
         .apply {

            val source = ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
               .createMediaSource(MediaItem.fromUri(Uri.parse(source)))

            setMediaSource(source)
            prepare()
            addListener(playerListener)
            }
    }

 private fun play() {
      player?.playWhenReady = true
 }

 private fun releasePlayer() {
        player?.apply {
            playWhenReady = false
            release()
        }
        player = null
    }

 private val playerListener = object : Player.Listener {
     @OptIn(UnstableApi::class)
     override fun onPlaybackStateChanged(playbackState: Int) {
          super.onPlaybackStateChanged(playbackState)
          when (playbackState) {
             STATE_READY -> {
                 binding.playerview.player = player
                 binding.playerview.resizeMode = AspectRatioFrameLayout.RESIZE_MODE_ZOOM
                 binding.playerview.hideController()
                 play()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is working but sometimes I get the error:

```
E/IAudioFlinger: createTrack returned error -12
E/AudioTrack: createTrack_l(8194608): AudioFlinger could not create track, status: -12 output 0
E/AudioTrack-JNI: Error -12 initializing AudioTrack
```

This leads that I cannot play anymore any video untill I reintall application.

There is stack trace from console:

> E/android.media.AudioTrack: Error code -20 when initializing
> AudioTrack. E/MediaCodecAudioRenderer: Audio sink error
> androidx.media3.exoplayer.audio.AudioSink$InitializationException:
> AudioTrack init failed 0 Config(48000, 12, 48000) Format(2, null,
> null, audio/raw, null, -1, ```, [-1, -1, -1.0, null], [2, 48000])
> at androidx.media3.exoplayer.audio.DefaultAudioSink$Configuration.buildAudioTrack(DefaultAudioSink.java:2087)
> at androidx.media3.exoplayer.audio.DefaultAudioSink.buildAudioTrack(DefaultAudioSink.java:1029)
> at androidx.media3.exoplayer.audio.DefaultAudioSink.buildAudioTrackWithRetry(DefaultAudioSink.java:1008)
> at androidx.media3.exoplayer.audio.DefaultAudioSink.initializeAudioTrack(DefaultAudioSink.java:794)
> at androidx.media3.exoplayer.audio.DefaultAudioSink.handleBuffer(DefaultAudioSink.java:886)
> at androidx.media3.exoplayer.audio.MediaCodecAudioRenderer.processOutputBuffer(MediaCodecAudioRenderer.java:732)
> at androidx.media3.exoplayer.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.drainOutputBuffer(MediaCodecRenderer.java:1982)
> at androidx.media3.exoplayer.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.render(MediaCodecRenderer.java:862)
> at androidx.media3.exoplayer.ExoPlayerImplInternal.doSomeWork(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:1079)
> at androidx.media3.exoplayer.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:529)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
> at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
> Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot create AudioTrack
> at android.media.AudioTrack$Builder.build(AudioTrack.java:1277)
> at androidx.media3.exoplayer.audio.DefaultAudioSink$Configuration.createAudioTrackV29(DefaultAudioSink.java:2134)
> at androidx.media3.exoplayer.audio.DefaultAudioSink$Configuration.createAudioTrack(DefaultAudioSink.java:2113)
> at androidx.media3.exoplayer.audio.DefaultAudioSink$Configuration.buildAudioTrack(DefaultAudioSink.java:2079)
> at androidx.media3.exoplayer.audio.DefaultAudioSink.buildAudioTrack(DefaultAudioSink.java:1029) 
> at androidx.media3.exoplayer.audio.DefaultAudioSink.buildAudioTrackWithRetry(DefaultAudioSink.java:1008) 
> at androidx.media3.exoplayer.audio.DefaultAudioSink.initializeAudioTrack(DefaultAudioSink.java:794) 
> at androidx.media3.exoplayer.audio.DefaultAudioSink.handleBuffer(DefaultAudioSink.java:886) 
> at androidx.media3.exoplayer.audio.MediaCodecAudioRenderer.processOutputBuffer(MediaCodecAudioRenderer.java:732) 
> at androidx.media3.exoplayer.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.drainOutputBuffer(MediaCodecRenderer.java:1982) 
> at androidx.media3.exoplayer.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.render(MediaCodecRenderer.java:862) 
> at androidx.media3.exoplayer.ExoPlayerImplInternal.doSomeWork(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:1079) 
> at androidx.media3.exoplayer.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:529) 
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
> at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)  E/IAudioFlinger: createTrack returned error -12 E/AudioTrack:
> createTrack_l(16): AudioFlinger could not create track, status: -12
> output 0 E/AudioTrack-JNI: Error -12 initializing AudioTrack
> D/AudioTrack: gather(): no metrics gathered, track status=-12